# How can I start a program from a tkinter menu with an argument without blocking?

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I am trying to make a tkinter menu to call various executable programs. I'm using named subroutines, so lambda isn't an issue.

Python 3.4, Windows 7.

Using various methods, I have one or both of the following problems:

1. screen I/O doesn't work in the called program until the menu exits, and
2. I can't pass an argument to the program I'm calling

It seems that subprocess.Popen or startfile avoid the first problem, but I can't get them to accept an argument.

Here is a short example, with various unsuccessful tries:

```
from tkinter import *
import os, subprocess

def doit(cmd):
#   res=os.system(cmd)  # doesn't return to system prompt till tk closed
    res=os.startfile(cmd) # doesn't return to system prompt
def dir():
    res=os.system('dir')    # doesn't return to system prompt
def AllWeather():
    vres=os.system('AllWeather.htm')
def Homburg():
#   res=os.startfile('c:\perl\hsf\options\HomburgPlan.pl') # can't pass argument
#   res=os.system('c:\perl\hsf\options\HomburgPlan.pl PG') # hangs on input request till tk closed
#   res=os.startfile('c:\perl\hsf\options\HomburgPlan.pl', 'PG') # thinks PG is an applicaiton 
#   res=subprocess.call('c:\perl\hsf\options\HomburgPlan.pl PG') #thinks PG is part of filename 
#   res=subprocess.Popen('c:\perl\hsf\options\HomburgPlan.pl', 'PG') # error in buffer size 
    res=subprocess.Popen(('c:\perl\hsf\options\HomburgPlan.pl', 'PG'))  #makes arg a list, Win error 193

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Files", menu=filemenu)

filemenu.add_command(label="Dir", command=dir) # no good - executes but hangs till tk closed
#filemenu.add_command(label="Dir", command=os.system('dir')) # no good - dir gets executed immediately
#filemenu.add_command(label="Dir", command=doit('dir')) # no good - dir gets executed immediately
#filemenu.add_command(label="Dir", command="doit('dir')")# no good, dir is not executed when clicked

filemenu.add_command(label="Homburg", command=Homburg)
filemenu.add_command(label="AllWeather", command=AllWeather)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

What would be the proper way to define the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
def Homburg():
    res=subprocess.Popen(['c:\perl\hsf\options\HomburgPlan.pl', 'PG'])
```

When you use `Popen` with `shell=False` (the default) the command arguments should be passed in a list to the `Popen` constructor.

This is basically the same as the one you tried that gave you a "Win error 193". [Error 193 maps to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` I think you can get rid of that by passing the full path to the perl executable as the first argument in the list, then the path to the perl script, then `'PG'`:

```
res=subprocess.Popen(['c:\perl\perl.exe', 'c:\perl\hsf\options\HomburgPlan.pl', 'PG'])  # I'm completely guessing about where perl.exe is
```

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work, but the second one aced it!!